# Div shows/hides after second click with ajax and django

Tags: ajax, django-views, django-templates

i want to have simple functionality in my app. When user clicks on "show replies" button, div with class "replies" will show up, then button changes to "hide replies" and when click it again the div will disappear. I am close but the problem is: when I click on button first time (after reloading page), the button changes to "hide", data is not showing up. Until i click it second time it shows and then i have data and button "show replies". In other words: ajax call doesn't work on first time, data prints properly even with first click. Please help me to understand what is wrong.

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showReplies").click(function () {
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("data-href"),
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(`#${id}.replies`).html(data);
                let text = $(`#${id}.showReplies`).text()
                if (text == 'Show replies') {
                    text = 'Hide replies'
                    $(`#${id}.showReplies`).text(text)
                } else {
                    text = 'Show replies'
                    $(`#${id}.showReplies`).text(text)
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

template

```
<button type="button" id="{{ comment.id }}" class="showReplies btn btn-link" data-href="{% url 'comment_replies' comment.id %}">Show replies</button>
    <div class="replies" id="{{ comment.id }}" style="margin-left: 30px;">
        {% include 'blog/comment_replies.html' %}
    </div>
```

urls

```
path('comment_replies/<int:comment_id>/', comment_replies, name='comment_replies')
```

view

```
def comment_replies(request, comment_id):
    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    replies = Reply.objects.filter(comment=comment)
    context = {'replies': replies}
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_replies.html', context)
```

Comment: can you do alert inside your `if`and see if that alert shows ?

Comment: I must say that i removed line `$(`#${id}.replies`).toggle();` from right above ajax and it was still toggling, but when i run the code today, it stopped and when i put the line back toggle stopped working and div shows on first click...

Comment: does `data` has `.showReplies` text which you are accessing here `$('#${id}.showReplies').text()`?

Comment: No, it does not, it has template content with replies

Comment: your code seems ok to me. May be problem is somewhere else . Also make sure `text` has right value .

Comment: this is what console logs:
<p>test</p>
    <small>kropa / 05 September 2020</small>

    <p>test2</p>
    <small>kropa / 06 September 2020</small>

Comment: Additionally there is new, very annoying problem that work of my ajax doesn't change after changing code. Only after few hours toggle func started work and now I cannot change anything. But lets sum up: at the moment div hides/shows properly but not after first click. So when I click button firstly text button changes to "hide" but div is hidden and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221217/discussion-between-swati-and-bkrop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, @Swati found the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showReplies").click(function () {
        let id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("data-href"),
            type: 'get',

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $(`#${id}.replies`).html(data);
                let text = $(`#${id}.showReplies`).text();
                console.log(text);
                if (text == 'Show replies') {
                    text = 'Hide';
                    $(`#${id}.showReplies`).text(text);
                    $(`#${id}.replies`).show();
                } else {
                    text = 'Show replies';
                    $(`#${id}.showReplies`).text(text);
                    $(`#${id}.replies`).hide();
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I had to add `$(`#${id}.replies`).show();`and `$(`#${id}.replies`).hide();`in `if` and `else`.